# Android WebView adding Uploading Download Copy and Paste and Cookie Manager

Tags: android, file-upload, webview, copy-paste, android-download-manager

I'm trying to create a app for my forum so users don't have to user the browser on their mobile device or use another app. I'm running into the issue of the app crashing right now, but am not sure why. I'm a newbie at this so really don't know what to look for when it comes to errors in code, maybe I could get some help figuring out what I'm doing wrong?

I may need to change something in the code so feel free to let me know but show me what it would need to be changed to please. I also need to figure out how to add the copy and paste feature to the app along with the ability to have the app set a cookie for "remember me".

```
package com.technologx.technologx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Adds Progress Bar Support
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        // Makes Progress Bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        // Use forum.xml as webview layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Adds Zoom Control (You may not need this)
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        // Enables Multi-Touch. if supported by ROM
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        initWebView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl("https://technologx.com"); // TODO input your url

        // This will handle downloading. It requires Gingerbread, though
        final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        // This is where downloaded files will be written, using the package name isn't required
        // but it's a good way to communicate who owns the directory
        final File destinationDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getPackageName());
        if (!destinationDir.exists()) {
            destinationDir.mkdir(); // Don't forget to make the directory if it's not there
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
                boolean shouldOverride = false;
                // We only want to handle requests for mp3 files, everything else the webview
                // can handle normally
                if (url.endsWith(".zip")) {
                    shouldOverride = true;
                    Uri source = Uri.parse(url);

                    // Make a new request pointing to the mp3 url
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                    // Use the same file name for the destination
                    File destinationFile = new File (destinationDir, source.getLastPathSegment());
                    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));
                    // Add it to the manager
                    manager.enqueue(request);
                }
                return shouldOverride;
            }
        });

    }

    private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
            m.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void initWebView(WebView webView) {

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.clearCache(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);
    }

    UploadHandler mUploadHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == Controller.FILE_SELECTED) {
            // Chose a file from the file picker.
            if (mUploadHandler != null) {
                mUploadHandler.onResult(resultCode, intent);
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        public MyWebChromeClient() {

        }

        private String getTitleFromUrl(String url) {
            String title = url;
            try {
                URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                String host = urlObj.getHost();
                if (host != null && !host.isEmpty()) {
                    return urlObj.getProtocol() + "://" + host;
                }
                if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
                    String fileName = urlObj.getFile();
                    if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                        return fileName;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }

            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;
            // return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.cancel();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;

            // return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        }

        // Android 2.x
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // Android 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "", "filesystem");
        }

        // Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadHandler = new UploadHandler(new Controller());
            mUploadHandler.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
        }

        // Android 4.4, 4.4.1, 4.4.2
        // openFileChooser function is not called on Android 4.4, 4.4.1, 4.4.2,
        // you may use your own java script interface or other hybrid framework.

        // Android 5.0.1
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            String acceptTypes[] = fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes();

            String acceptType = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < acceptTypes.length; ++ i) {
                if (acceptTypes[i] != null && acceptTypes[i].length() != 0)
                    acceptType += acceptTypes[i] + ";";
            }
            if (acceptType.length() == 0)
                acceptType = "*/*";

            final ValueCallback<Uri[]> finalFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            ValueCallback<Uri> vc = new ValueCallback<Uri>() {

                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(Uri value) {

                    Uri[] result;
                    if (value != null)
                        result = new Uri[]{value};
                    else
                        result = null;

                    finalFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(result);

                }
            };

            openFileChooser(vc, acceptType, "filesystem");


            return true;
        }
    };

    class Controller {
        final static int FILE_SELECTED = 4;

        Activity getActivity() {
            return MainActivity.this;
        }
    }


    // public class UploadHandler {

    class UploadHandler {
        /*
         * The Object used to inform the WebView of the file to upload.
         */
        private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
        private String mCameraFilePath;
        private boolean mHandled;
        private boolean mCaughtActivityNotFoundException;
        private Controller mController;
        public UploadHandler(Controller controller) {
            mController = controller;
        }
        String getFilePath() {
            return mCameraFilePath;
        }
        boolean handled() {
            return mHandled;
        }
        void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && mCaughtActivityNotFoundException) {
                // Couldn't resolve an activity, we are going to try again so skip
                // this result.
                mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
                return;
            }
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            // As we ask the camera to save the result of the user taking
            // a picture, the camera application does not return anything other
            // than RESULT_OK. So we need to check whether the file we expected
            // was written to disk in the in the case that we
            // did not get an intent returned but did get a RESULT_OK. If it was,
            // we assume that this result has came back from the camera.
            if (result == null && intent == null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                File cameraFile = new File(mCameraFilePath);
                if (cameraFile.exists()) {
                    result = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
                    // Broadcast to the media scanner that we have a new photo
                    // so it will be added into the gallery for the user.
                    mController.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
                }
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mHandled = true;
            mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
        }
        void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            final String imageMimeType = "image/*";
            final String videoMimeType = "video/*";
            final String audioMimeType = "audio/*";
            final String mediaSourceKey = "capture";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamera = "camera";
            final String mediaSourceValueFileSystem = "filesystem";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamcorder = "camcorder";
            final String mediaSourceValueMicrophone = "microphone";
            // According to the spec, media source can be 'filesystem' or 'camera' or 'camcorder'
            // or 'microphone' and the default value should be 'filesystem'.
            String mediaSource = mediaSourceValueFileSystem;
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                // Already a file picker operation in progress.
                return;
            }
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Parse the accept type.
            String params[] = acceptType.split(";");
            String mimeType = params[0];
            if (capture.length() > 0) {
                mediaSource = capture;
            }
            if (capture.equals(mediaSourceValueFileSystem)) {
                // To maintain backwards compatibility with the previous implementation
                // of the media capture API, if the value of the 'capture' attribute is
                // "filesystem", we should examine the accept-type for a MIME type that
                // may specify a different capture value.
                for (String p : params) {
                    String[] keyValue = p.split("=");
                    if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                        // Process key=value parameters.
                        if (mediaSourceKey.equals(keyValue[0])) {
                            mediaSource = keyValue[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Ensure it is not still set from a previous upload.
            mCameraFilePath = null;
            if (mimeType.equals(imageMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamera)) {
                    // Specified 'image/*' and requested the camera, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camera directly.
                    startActivity(createCameraIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'image/*', capture=filesystem, or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show a traditional picker filetered on accept type
                    // so launch an intent for both the Camera and image/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(imageMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(videoMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamcorder)) {
                    // Specified 'video/*' and requested the camcorder, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camcorder directly.
                    startActivity(createCamcorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'video/*', capture=filesystem or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show an intent for the traditional file picker, filtered
                    // on accept type so launch an intent for both camcorder and video/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCamcorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(videoMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(audioMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueMicrophone)) {
                    // Specified 'audio/*' and requested microphone, so go ahead and launch the sound
                    // recorder.
                    startActivity(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'audio/*',  capture=filesystem of an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases so go ahead and launch an intent for both the sound
                    // recorder and audio/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(audioMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            }
            // No special handling based on the accept type was necessary, so trigger the default
            // file upload chooser.
            startActivity(createDefaultOpenableIntent());
        }
        private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
            try {
                mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // No installed app was able to handle the intent that
                // we sent, so fallback to the default file upload control.
                try {
                    mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = true;
                    mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(createDefaultOpenableIntent(),
                            Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
                    // Nothing can return us a file, so file upload is effectively disabled.
                    Toast.makeText(mController.getActivity(), R.string.uploads_disabled,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        private Intent createDefaultOpenableIntent() {
            // Create and return a chooser with the default OPENABLE
            // actions including the camera, camcorder and sound
            // recorder where available.
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent(), createCamcorderIntent(),
                    createSoundRecorderIntent());
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, i);
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createChooserIntent(Intent... intents) {
            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,
                    mController.getActivity().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.choose_upload));
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createOpenableIntent(String type) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType(type);
            return i;
        }
        private Intent createCameraIntent() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                    File.separator + "browser-photos");
            cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
            mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath)));
            return cameraIntent;
        }
        private Intent createCamcorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
        private Intent createSoundRecorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // Removes Progress Bar
            findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Adds Cookies. Yummy!
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        }
}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Enables going back history
        if (webView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            // Your exit alert code, or alternatively line below to finish
            // Finishes forum activity
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the logcat data:

```
12 - 18 03: 12: 53.095 28851 - 28851 / com.technologx.technologx E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
    main
Process: com.technologx.technologx, PID: 28851

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {
    com.technologx.technologx / com.technologx.technologx.MainActivity
}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)'
on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2441)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1349)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5431)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 914)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 707)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)'
on a null object reference
at com.technologx.technologx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java: 47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 6056)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2332)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2441)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1349)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5431)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 914)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 707)
```

Comment: Looks like the `java.lang.NullPointerException` is where you should be looking. Could it be that you are calling `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())` prior to setting the instance variable `webView`?

Comment: @halfer I'm not sure to be honest like I said I'm a noob at Android coding I'm better with creating websites or writing scripts for iDevices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I fixed the crash by adding this:  'WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());'  below the 'initWebView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl("https://technologx.com"); // TODO input your url' now the progress bar isn't working correctly.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit - meta/voting commentary does not belong in posts. If you wish to comment about a suggested duplicate, then use the comment system for that. This question is almost certainly a duplicate of the question I have indicated, anyway - you had an NPE and you solved your NPE. The duplicate is about NPEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note I am not a Java programmer. At a guess though, when you declare this, it will be a null object reference:

```
private WebView webView;
```

So in these two lines, you are trying to do something with this (null) object, and then you set the object to a instance (which is presumably not null):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

This is consistent with your error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)'
>   on a null object reference

An object that is null is not really an object at all, it is just null, and so you cannot perform an operation on it. Why not try swapping those last two lines around, and see if that helps?

Comment: I fixed the crash by adding this: 'WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview); // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());' below the 'initWebView(webView); webView.loadUrl("technologx.com"); // TODO input your url' now the progress bar isn't working correctly.

Comment: Yep, that looks like my solution too @Technologx. Great!

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem @Technologx, which would be best framed in a new question. Remember that readers are generally unlikely to download your code and debug it for themselves (since there is not enough time in the day to help everyone in that fashion). Ask a new question, show your new error, add a new screenshot if necessary, and if you can, show what you have done to resolve the problem yourself. It is very good practice!

Comment: So how do I get the progressbar to work correctly now it's not working at all and staying on the screen the whole time the app is open? Android Studio is saying FEATURE_PROGRESS & PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON is deprecated.

Comment: Alright @halfer there really isn't a error for the progressbar.

Comment: Great @Technologx, so you have something to put in a new question. The deprecated messages may be relevant (though I won't be able to assist, NPEs are about the limit of my Java know-how!).

Comment: That's ok @halfer if your unable to help but thank you for helping on this.